# Remapping dell keyboard shortcut buttons

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, windows-registry, button-remapping

So I have a dell sk-8135
[keyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ot2PT.jpg) that has a few shortcut keys up top, which includes Back, Forward, Stop, Refresh, Homepage, Email, My Computer, and Calc. I've been able to modify these by editing the AppKey key in the registry at `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\AppKey`

AppKey has 8 subkeys 1, 2, 4, 3, 7, 15, 17, 18 (Listed in order compared to my keyboards buttons)

In "Forward" which is AppKey 1, I have it running a ShellExecute which works properly, but the only problem is **it still thinks I'm pressing the forward key**, but it does properly do the ShellExecute at the same time. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2MVR5.jpg) are the ProcessMonitor results when I press the backward shortcut (and when i press an unedited shortcut button).

Is there anyway for me to completely disable the backward/forward/refresh buttons while still being able to do ShellExecute?

Note: The Mail, My Computer and Calc dont apply to this, as they only launch my hotkey setup, and not the hotkey along with itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix this by compiling a java program to run in the background to block the key. [This is the code I used.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2486167/is-it-is-possible-to-disable-the-windows-keys-using-java)

Now, this program disabled the key AND the registry call, so I just stuck this under "case: 0x__"

```
try {
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\Program Files\\AutoHotkey\\AutoHotkey.exe \"C:\\Program Files\\AutoHotkey\\auto.ahk\"");
} catch (IOException e) {  }
```